# Align on left does not works

Tags: css, alignment

If you check my website in the German version, for example, everything is aligned on left. But this does not works on English or French version. Infact the section that start with "For all your asset" looks like floated on right, but is not. The code is the same for all the version.
Can i fix it?

Comment: Can you insert images of your problem. It looks fine to me. 
I think i found the problem. Your `font-size: 1.5rem !important; */` seems to move it to the left.

Comment: @MarLen image added into first post

Comment: The left align won't work because your middle paragraph is a bit longer. I tested it by adding another `<h3>` above. This makes the second <h3> work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sections Stage, Solutions and Approach are floated to the left. The problem is that this float is not cleared after the elements.

In this specific case you can use the following CSS to clear it:

```
#services {
    clear: both;
}
```

The reason why the problem doesn’t appear in the German version is that there the right section is longer than the other ones. In the English version the middle section is longer and produces the problem.

Comment: Would be great to see a vote up if it helped and even a mark that this is the correct answer. ;)